# How to prove this equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$ are the eigen values of a matrix

$\begin{bmatrix} 26 & -2 & 2 \\ 2 & 21 & 4 \\ 4 & 2 &28 \end{bmatrix}$

Then Show that $\sqrt{\lambda_1^2+\lambda_2^2+\lambda_3^2} \le \sqrt{1949}$

What i could think of the normal way in which i find the three eigen values and put them in the equation to check. but that is probably not right as i need to prove the given inequality

Comment: Hint: If you square your matrix, what are the eigenvalues of the resulting matrix? Do you know an easy way to compute the sum of the eigenvalues of a matrix?

Comment: Yours is a fine approach.  There may be easier ones, but finding the eigenvalues and verifying the inequality is sufficient.

Comment: oh ! is there an easy way to calculate the sum of eigen values of the matrices ? i didn't know. can your please post a link for the same ? i see a solution now :)

Comment: The trace of a matrix is the sum of the eigenvalues

Comment: Investigate the trace of a matrix (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)) - given the inequality I suspect you are not supposed to use this, but rather to make some estimate based on what you have learned so far about eigenvalues.

Comment: @RossMillikan The inequality seems to be related to the sum of the squares of entries in the original matrix - that's the only way I can easily find $1949$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for the matrix $A$ and $P$ is a polynomial then $P(\lambda)$ is an eigenvalue for $P(A)$.

Let $P(x)=x^2$ and notice that $$\sum_i \lambda_i^2=\mathrm{tr}(A^2)$$

Comment: but isn't trace of matrix equal to sum of eigen value in only diagonal or triangular matrix ? as in those matrix, the eigen values are the diagonal elements

Comment: No that isn't true the trace is invariant for the class of similarity of a matrix.

Comment: okie, Thanks :)

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane $~\huge\color{green}{+}~$Because your answer was helpful :)

Comment: @Software This makes me happy and you're welcome :)